# retrieving contacts from my Google account

Tags: google-contacts

I stored my contacts to my Google account however I lost my phone and had my service suspended now I have a new phone I'm not sure how to retrieve them I was under the impression that once I  logged into my account they would automatically be stored in my phone

Answer (score 0):

If they are in your Google account, once you log into Google via your phone it should sync your Contacts.  You may want to check to make sure that Contacts is checked under Settings - Accounts - your Google account.